# Detect undiscovered user stories

Tags: agile, user-stories

Created user stories for a specific project but not sure if I'm missing to write down some that were hard to spot.

In order to not cause (or reduce) development headaches, how can I detect previously undiscovered (missing, implied, and assumed) user stories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're truly agile, there's no harm in missing user stories. Your business people, including customer and stakeholder representatives, are working closely with the development team. You are regularly delivering working software that the stakeholders or stakeholder representatives can use and provide feedback on. You are responsive as the requirements change (or you identify things that you've missed), using the short delivery cycles as feedback loops.

A missing (or incomplete or wrong) requirement, in any format, shouldn't be missing (or incomplete or wrong) for long. If, for any reason, you aren't getting rapid feedback from stakeholders or stakeholder representatives, the delivery team and delivery organization should be reflecting on how to become more effective - how to identify what is most important, how to deliver those most important pieces of functionality quickly, and how to elicit and respond to feedback on the delivered functionality - on a regular basis.

Comment: Ok so what you are proposing is to jump into dev as it is and eventually the undiscovered user-stories will appear. Understood, that was in fact my initial thought.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres I wouldn't say "jump right into dev". You should do some work up-front to understand the user problems and needs and translate those into some kind of requirements (such as user stories, with acceptance criteria, that are at a sufficient level to build). You can order those by priority or importance or relative value to users and then look at adding in technical dependencies (which may reorder some of the work) and now that you have a backlog of work, start iterating on that.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the guidance Thomas Owens!