# When to know I'm ready to start developing

Tags: agile, software-development, user-stories

Created user stories for a specific software development project and, [from my last question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/25959/27189), learned to just jump into dev even though there might exist undiscovered user stories.

Still, i wonder... When to know I'm ready to start with development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a question for the team to discuss amongst themselves and decide on what feels right.

If you are using the Scrum Framework a good guide is that you have a minimum of enough *ready* user stories to cover the first sprint.

Keep in mind that if you only have one sprints worth of stories that you will likely need to spend a sizeable fraction of the first sprint preparing for the next sprint. So try not to take in too much work so that you have sufficient time for this.

Going forward, the number of ready stories you have will depend on your team's approach and on the nature of your organisation. Good advice would be to just get started and then adapt if you find you are often running out of prepared stories.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance Barnaby Golden!

Answer (score 1):

The development in itself and the way it is organized, is left to the development team.

So, if your question is **when to start the Sprint or the Timebox** (the first step of which being a *planning* or *kick-off*), I would say it is a conjunction of the 3 following points :

1. when you have to, according to the delivery date agreed with the customer;
   **AND**
2. when the estimates of the topmost backlog's user-stories (with highest priority) are precise enough;
   **AND**
3. when you have enough work to fill a sprint (according to the team capacity).

That being said, you should always be ready to start the next sprint when the current sprint ends.